# Question about finding a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $\beta<1,$ is $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{m^{2-\beta}}{n^{3-\beta}} = \frac{1}{3-\beta}$?

$\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{m^{2}}{n^{3}} = \frac{1}{3}$ and so I was guessing that would be the case but am not sure how to prove it? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Riemann sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are very correct.

Even without using Riemann sums as Simply Beautiful Art commented
$$S_n=\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{m^{2-\beta}}{n^{3-\beta}}=\frac{1}{n^{3-\beta}}\sum_{m=1}^n {m^{2-\beta}}=n^{\beta -3} H_n^{(\beta -2)}$$ where appear the generalized harmonic numbers.

Using the corresponding asymptotics for large values of $n$
$$H_n^{(\beta -2)}=n^{2-\beta } \left(\frac{n}{3-\beta }+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2-\beta}{12n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)+\zeta (\beta -2)$$ you can conclude.